# How can I import images

Tags: java, image

Dear stackoverflow community,

How do I import an image?
I tried this code:

Main class:

```
private DisplayImage panel;

public ImportImage() throws IOException, InterruptedException {   
    this.setSize(new Dimension(1500, 1500));
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    panel = new DisplayImage();

    this.add(panel);

    this.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ImportImage iI = new ImportImage();
}
```

and the panel class:

```
BufferedImage img;

public DisplayImage() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String imgPath = "imageimport.png";
    img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imgPath));
    sleep(300);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}
```

When I start the program, it outputs nothing, not even an error.
It runs endless and doesn't even stop until I stop the program myself.
The Image is on the same folder with the main and panel class.
Corrections for this code or better suggestions doesn't matter.
And sorry about the bad english, it's not my native language, but I'm still learning/studying it.

Comment: Debug it, in order to know what are in img before sleep(300);

Comment: Why don't you pass the image path into the constructor?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing File I/O on the GUI thread. And using sleep to make "sure" the image is loaded before paint is called is not only a code smell but a code stench ...

Comment: Display a "Loading" message and load the image in the background, then replace the message with the image when it has finished loading.

Comment: ..or try repaint after `g.drawImage`

Comment: sorry my answer was wrong! I will remove it when you tell us how you solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ACHTUNG This answer is wrong!**
[Looking at the API I see my error](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver))

---

You have set the width and height in `g.drawImage`to 0. Set them to the size of the image.

You get the width and height from `img.getWidth()` and `img.getHeight()`

Btw. what is the point of having the thread sleeping?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought `g.drawImage` does set the width or height automaticly, but could that be possible?

Comment: getting the width and height from img

Comment: well you are explicitly telling Graphics to set them to zero.

Comment: @MichaelZiegler I see now that my answer is wrong!! the 0's were X and Y! Did it really help Michael?

Comment: Well, I first read that the width and height in `g.drawImage` was been set to 0, so I thought, I should set Width and Height to 100 and it worked. And to answer to your second question: A friend told me to write the thread sleep because he said that the image has to load. But it turned out wrong.

Comment: @MichaelZiegler yes but `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null)` sets the x and y to 0 not the width and height. The width and height should be known by the method. I don't get it :/

Comment: @JackFlamp I doublechecked my image. My conclusion: The file is too big. I didn't noticed that when I edited my image, it was 3600x1800 pixel big. Maybe that's the issue. I apologize you for making trouble :/.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for info.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your code as following, it is working for me

```
package com.importimage;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 * @author elias.shaik
 *
 */
public class ImportImage extends JFrame{
    private DisplayImage panel;

    public ImportImage() throws IOException, InterruptedException {   
        this.setSize(new Dimension(1500, 1500));
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel = new DisplayImage();

        this.add(panel);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ImportImage iI = new ImportImage();
    }
}

package com.importimage;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * @author elias.shaik
 *
 */
public class DisplayImage extends JPanel{
    BufferedImage img;

    public DisplayImage() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String imgPath = "mavenSrpingStructure.PNG";
        img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imgPath));
        Thread.sleep(300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the preferred size of your panel after the image loads.

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
```

### App

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class App implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Image Frame");
        ImagePanel p = new ImagePanel("resources/Batman.jpg");

        p.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
            @Override public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) { }
            @Override public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) { }
            @Override public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) { }

            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                if (e.getComponent() instanceof ImagePanel) {
                    f.setTitle(((ImagePanel) e.getComponent()).getFilename());
                }
            }
        });

        f.setContentPane(p);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new App());
    }
}
```

### ImagePanel

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private BufferedImage image;
    private String filename;

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public ImagePanel(String path) {
        super();
        try {
            updateImage(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void updateImage(String path) throws IOException {
        image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));

        if (image != null) {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));

            Path p = Paths.get(path);
            filename = p.getFileName().toString();
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (image != null) {
            g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
}
```